# :remote => true creating unknown format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Check this out. I've got a fairly simple form that's created with the following syntax:

```
<%= form_for([@issue, @issue_order], :remote => true) do |f| %>
```

The form, due to logic on the page, is actually called via javascript, like this:

```
$('#new_issue_order')[0].submit()
```

The controller handles the ajax request by doing a bit of logic then throwing out a little something like this:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
```

The AJAX that handles this response is in the following javascript:

```
$('#new_issue_order').on('ajax:success', issueOrder.processOrder)
..........
  processOrder: function(e, data, status, xhr) {
      $('.sign-up-errors').empty();
      errors = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Flash-Error').split(',');
      for (i=0; i < errors.length; i++) {
        $('.errors').append($('<p>' + errors[i] + '</p>'));
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.errors').empty();
      }, 3500);·
  }
```

I figured that would allow it to respond to the remote request, but what I get instead is the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

I tried creating a new.js.erb in my views (to correspond with the new page that it was on), but I'm still getting the same error. I haven't tried migrating my success handler AJAX to the new.js.erb code, because I'd prefer to keep my javascript handling in the javascript file in my assets for business reasons.

How can I get a seamless AJAX response? I've done it before, but respond_to has always confused me.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the js response template as `new.js.erb` is incorrect.

The form itself is within `new.html.erb` template, guessed by convention. So, the form's action is supposed to point to `#create`.

In order to response correctly to this form's submission, you need to create a js template as `create.js.erb`, and respond to js in `#create` action.

Besides, in most cases you don't need to manually set Ajax response in assets js like

```
$('#new_issue_order').on('ajax:success', issueOrder.processOrder)...
```

Instead, you can just do it within `create.js.erb`. For example

```
$('#new_issue_order').css('background', 'green')
```

This script will be run after `ajax:success` event.

Comment: Hmm. I'm still getting the unknown format issue even when I do that. I'd also like to know how to do it without needing the create.js.erb file.

Comment: Does the fact that I'm calling the submit() button with jQuery change what type of format is passed in?

Comment: Yes, very likely your custom script changed that. Don't use custom script unless you really need it. UJS is built for simpilify these cases. UJS hijacks submission of forms with remote true, sending the request to server using jQUery Ajax, with default type 'script`, which should response by `:js`

Comment: The rest of the logic requires me to submit the form by doing this code: $('#new_issue_order')[0].submit(). Is there any way to ensure that the format will still be passed as a proper AJAX call, or do I need to turn $('#new_issue_order')[0].submit() into a traditional jQuery AJAX call?

Comment: Even if you use script to submit the form say `submit()`, the submit event will also be triggered and UJS can hear that. So in theory no action needed. If you roll out your own Ajax call, there is really no need to use remote true on this form, you can set Ajax `dataType` as script manually. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/